# Split dynamic string[] into array of fixed size

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a `string[]` of dynamic size

```
String[] a = {'','',....dynamic values}
```

so size will be determined at runtime.

I need to split `String[]` a into fixed array size of 1000 say

```
String[] b = {first 1000 values of a}
String[] c = {next set of 1000 values of a}
```

Kindly help me achieve this.

Comment: Arrays have a fixed size.

Comment: @MarounMaroun He maybe means varargs which has a variable length

Comment: @YassinHajaj Could be, but it still worth correcting wrong semantics.

Comment: lets say a.length=2954 then i need String[]b = {first 1000 of a} String[]c = {next 1000 of a} String[] d = {954 of a}

Comment: I suggest you use `Arrays.copyOfRange` to copy the portions of the array you want. Or you could write you code so you don't need these copies in the first place.

Comment: Can you say why you need this?

Comment: i will put these values in sql in clause as it will take only 1000 values max

Comment: Can it take a `List<String>` instead? (As a List is more efficient to split up)

Comment: "sql will take only 1000 values max" It looks like you are trying to work around a different problem, which may be caused by a shortcoming in your design. You may be better off describing the big problem that caused you to look for a solution to this issue. I can nearly guarantee you that the big issue would not go away when you solve the split-by-1000-items problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Arrays.copyOfRange like this

```
    String[] a = {"a","b","c","d","r","g","f","h", ...};

    String[] b = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, 1000, String[].class);
    String[] c = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1000, a.length, String[].class);
```

but it crash if the length of 'a' is smaller than 1000 
so you can do this

```
    int range = (a.length < 1000) ? a.length : 1000;

    String[] b = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, range, String[].class);
    String[] c = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, range, a.length, String[].class);
```

if length of 'a' is smaller than 1000, 'b' has the same size like 'a'
so if you want to always have size of b 1000, you have to initialize 'b' with length of 1000

```
    String[] b = new String[1000]();
```

ant then fill it in forcycle

Comment: how can i dynamically initialize the no of String[] b,c,d etc say size of a=3000 then i should have 3 string[] b,c,d.

Comment: if you want dynamic count of String[] b, c, d, etc, with length of 1000... You need two dymensional string - String[][] str  = new String[a/1000][1000]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of multiple arrays, combine them in one, **two-dimensional** array.

```
int n = (int)Math.ceil(a.length/1000d); 
String str[][] = new String[n][1000]; //Two dimensional array
int x=0;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<1000 && x<a.length; j++)
    {
        str[i][j] = a[i];
        x++;
    }
}
```

Now if you want, then you may split that two dimensional array into multiple arrays.

Comment: Is `x<.length` in your outer for loop a typo?

Comment: @ManoDestra Oh yes. Sorry. Editing it.

Comment: suppose a.length = 2954 then n is ignoring the 954. I want to split the rest records in to another string array

Comment: @jack That was because `a.length/1000` returns `int`. Made it `a.length/1000d`. Now it will work!

Answer (score -1):

Arrays.copyOfRange(boolean[], int, int)
The 2nd int can be greater than the length of the array and will be rolled back to the length.